# How to configure FluentBit & OpenSearch so that json and non-json logs are handled correctly

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch, fluent-bit

We have multiple applications running under Kubernetes, written in Python, Go, Ruby and Elixer. We are using [Fluent Bit](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual) to forward all of the logs to [AWS Open Search](https://aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/). All of our components write their logs to STDOUT/STDERR. Some components write in JSON format, some in non-JSON text format. In Open Search UI, the full body of the JSON log entries is not parsed into individual fields, we see it with some metedata fields followed by a long json string. Here is an example:

[image]

Here is the full content of the `log` field copied from OpenSearch UI

```
2023-01-09T23:41:56.279212506Z stdout F {"level":"WARN","ts":1673307716278.9448,"caller":"internal/internal_task_pollers.go:348","message":"Failed to process workflow task.","Namespace":"ai-platform-dev.59ee7","TaskQueue":"WORKFLOW_QUEUE","WorkerID":"1@workflow-worker-ai-workflow-worker-6c445f59f7-pgn6v@","WorkflowType":"NotesProWorkflow","WorkflowID":"workflow_1169649613530771459_1664751006481316721","RunID":"1ae58130-62d6-4f6a-a6db-8789be13d567","Attempt":12530,"Error":"lookup failed for scheduledEventID to activityID: scheduleEventID: 36, activityID: 36"}
```

Notice that the `log` field extract above has some internal "fields" before the embedded json string starts, I mean this part

```
2023-01-09T23:41:56.279212506Z stdout F
```

I am starting to suspect that perhaps this non-JSON start to the `log` field causes the `es` fluent-bit output plugin to fail to parse/decode the json content, and then `es` plugin then does not deliver the sub-fields within the json to OpenSearch.

I am considering using a fluent-bit regex parser to extract only the internal json component of the log string, which I assume would then be parsed as json and forwarded to OpenSearch as individual fields.

I am going to try this PARSER config to use regex to extract just the json part of the log string into a new field called capturedJson and then decode that field as json (idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66852383/833960):

```
[PARSER]
     Format regex
     Name logging-parser
     Regex ^(?<timestamp>.*) (?<stream>.*) .* (?<capturedJson>{.*})$
     Decode_Field json capturedJson
     Time_Format %FT%H:%M:%S,%L
     Time_Key time
```

The components which log in a non-JSON format look fine in OpenSearch.

How can I configure FluentBit and OpenSearch to get both my json and non-json components to render correctly in OpenSearch?

Here is the current FluentBit config file which is shared by all components:

```
{
    "fluent-bit.conf": "[SERVICE]
            Parsers_File /fluent-bit/parsers/parsers.conf
        
        [INPUT]
            Name              tail
            Tag               kube.*
            Path              /var/log/containers/*.log
            DB                /var/log/flb_kube.db
            Parser            docker
            Docker_Mode       On
            Mem_Buf_Limit     5MB
            Skip_Long_Lines   On
            Refresh_Interval  10
        
        [FILTER]
            Name                kubernetes
            Match               kube.*
            Kube_URL            https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443
            Merge_Log           On
            Merge_Log_Key       data
            Keep_Log            On
            K8S-Logging.Parser  On
            K8S-Logging.Exclude On
            Buffer_Size         32k
        [OUTPUT]
            Name            es
            Match           *
            AWS_Region      us-west-2
            AWS_Auth        On
            Host            opensearch.my-domain.com
            Port            443
            TLS             On
            Retry_Limit     6
            Replace_Dots    On
            Index my-index-name
            AWS_STS_Endpoint https://sts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
        "
}
```

Here is an extract from the `parsers.conf`

```
bash-4.2# cat parsers.conf 
...
[PARSER]
    Name   json
    Format json
    Time_Key time
    Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z

[PARSER]
    Name         docker
    Format       json
    Time_Key     time
    Time_Format  %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L
    Time_Keep    On
    # --
    # Since Fluent Bit v1.2, if you are parsing Docker logs and using
    # the Kubernetes filter, it's not longer required to decode the
    # 'log' key.
    #
    # Command      |  Decoder | Field | Optional Action
    # =============|==================|=================
    #Decode_Field_As    json     log
...
```

In OpenSearch I see the full log payload in a field called `log` it is defined as a
[image]

If I do a get on the index in Elastic and look for the `log` field, I see:

```
GET my-index-name
{
}
```

```
...
        "log" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
...
```

Should I modify the type of the `log` field to be [dynamic](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/opensearch/mappings/#dynamic-mapping)? Do I also need to change anything in the FluentBit config?

Even my components which normally log as json, will still sometimes emit non-json formatted output to STDERR if for example some error condition has occurred that bypasses the application log processing. Can this also be handled?

We are using:

- FluentBit 1.8.x
- OpenSearch 1.3

I think this is relevant to my issue: https://github.com/microsoft/fluentbit-containerd-cri-o-json-log/blob/main/config.yaml

Comment: yes, will put the answer in when I have time

Comment: kindly reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the CRI parser as explained in the
[Official Documentation](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/installation/kubernetes#container-runtime-interface-cri-parser)

```
[PARSER]
    # http://rubular.com/r/tjUt3Awgg4
    Name cri
    Format regex
    Regex ^(?<time>[^ ]+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) (?<logtag>[^ ]*) (?<message>.*)$
    Time_Key    time
    Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z

[PARSER]
    Name   json
    Format json
```

Then you should leverage fluentbit Filters to configure additional parser on the input

```
[Filter]
    Name Parser
    Match *
    Parser cri
    Key_Name message

[Filter]
    Name Parser
    Match *
    Parser json
    Key_Name log
```